# How do I get a parameter to print in TypeScript once I have assigned its type?

Tags: typescript

I have two files. One file I am exporting the `Person` class with a constructor that has data of type `any`.

In the second file I am importing the `Person` class, and I have a function that returns an output string based on the imported class.

My goal was to print information in this second file which utilized the imported class. Unfortunately, I am only able to get typescript to print out the function object and not what the function is returning.

This is the file I am importing:

```
export class Person {
firstName: string;
middleName: string;
lastName: string;

constructor(data?: any) {
    this.firstName = data.firstName || 'Jake';
    this.lastName = data.lastName || 'Jeffries';
    this.middleName = data.middleName;    
 }
}
```

And this is the file I am trying to get the results from:

```
import { Person } from './person.model';

function printPerson(person: Person) {
return `This should print along with the first name of person type, 
${person.firstName}!`    
}


console.log(printPerson("Jacob"));
```

This should print out:

`"This should print along with the first name of person type,Jacob"`

but instead I get the error:

> "Argument of type Jacob is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'".

If I try just console logging `printPerson()`, then I get only the function object printed out and not the message inside the function.

My question is, what argument will work for `printPerson()` so that I get the return of what is in that function?

Comment: Seems you're passing a string to printPerson(). Pass an object of type person instead.

Comment: Dacre, inside of the class Person, first.name is of type "string". How come TS won't recognize this when I try to print out person.firstName ?

Comment: @Ne0 you are missing the basic concepts of object orientated programming. You should probably learn them first.

Comment: @jetblack No I think I understood the concept. TS was expecting an instance of the class object. I could not bypass this and get solely a string when the type was a class.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently passing a string to the `printPerson()` function. The `printPerson()` function expects the first argument to be an instance of the `Person` class.

Consider making the following changes to solve this issue:

```
import { Person } from './person.model';

function printPerson(person: Person) {
   return `This should print along with the first name of person type,
   ${person.firstName}!`    
}

/* Create a person instance */
const jacobPerson = new Person({ 
    firstName : 'Jacob', 
    lastName : 'Smith', 
    middleName : 'E' 
});

/* Pass the person instance to printPerson() */
console.log(printPerson(jacobPerson));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your function with a parameter of type `Person` then for sure you can't pass a parameter for type `string`. Your function expects that an instance of the type `Person` is already allocated and initialized in some variable. 
However, I think you are trying to do this :

```
function printPerson(firstName: string) {
  const person = new Person({firstName, ...});
  console.log(person.firstName);
}
```